# Pulling same range from multiple sheets into master column

Tags: excel

I've 71 worksheets in the same workbook.

I want to create a master list of the values in `B27:B36` across all the worksheets, and count the number of times each specific value appears.

- The worksheets are numbered "1" to "71".
- For example, sheet "1" :

[image: Sheet 1]

- and sheet "2" :

[image: Sheet 2]

I managed to put this together

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&TabList&"'!B27:B36"),"5.1.1 (Policies for information security)",INDIRECT("'"&TabList&"'!B27:B36"),"5.1.1 (Policies for information security)"))
```

But the issue is I'd need a very long list of individual formulas to make that work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. My recommendation to solve this puzzle would be like this:  Into another sheet copy and paste all 71 ranges of `B27:B36` one under the other (via a vba macro of course).    You will have a one column 710 rows of data.  Select this data and create a pivot table to count the number of times each specific value appears.

Comment: This is something you can do with a VBA Macro. Assuming you are not familiar with vba, I will show you the way to start it: You can record a macro (pls google if your dont know how to do it) for some copy paste operations from lets say 5 sheets to the main one in which you will collect data. Then stop your macro and analyse the codes (to see the codes hit Alt + F8, and then click edit).  Try to understand the logic.  Then do a quick search of `do while` and `loop` vba commands and then edit your code to perform copy paste operations for all 71 sheets.  Let us know if you need help on the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the long but informative way into the comment section.  You can refer to this in future for similar problems.  I pasted below the vba macro you need.  After running this macro and collected all data in the main sheet, select this data and create a pivot table to count the number of times each specific value appears.  To do this put your datafield into the row section of pivot and then put it to data section as well and select count function. Your pivot will look like below screenshot.

[image: your pivot will look like this]

```
Sub Macro1()

i = 1
j = 2
 
Do Until i = 5
 
    Sheets("" & i & "").Select
    Range("G27:G36").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("main").Select
    Range("A" & j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 10
    
Loop
End Sub
```